# What is the difference between := and ::= in Toit?

Tags: toit

I'm writing code in Toit. In Toit programs, I can introduce fields and locals with either `:=` or `::=`.

```
main:
  hello := "Hello"
  log hello
  world ::= "World"
  log world
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `:=` introduces a field or a local that can be modified later (it is a variable), whereas `::=` introduces a 'final' field or local that has its value set exactly once.

The following code is legal and shows that you update the value of a local introduced with `:=`:

```
main:
  hello := "Hello"
  hello = "Greetings"
  log hello  // Logs 'Greetings'
```

The following code is illegal and shows that you cannot update the value of a local introduced with `::=`:

```
main:
  world ::= "World"
  world = "Universe"  // Error: Can't assign to final local
  log world
```